# Accessing active directory from wpf application without having to request / resend credentials

Tags: authentication, active-directory, credentials

I am writing a WPF application, and one feature I want to implement is the ability to display a list of computers in the domain. I have found some useful Active Directory code here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-Csharp-NET-3-5-.aspx

Typically code examples dealing with AD seem to require the user's credentials to make requests. But it occurs to me that if you are running the application from a computer that is part of the domain, the user has already provided user credentials sufficient to access AD on that domain controller, when logging on to the system.

Is there some way that the user can access AD via my application without the app having to ask the user to reenter the same credentials again? I mean is there some kind of token that I can forward that indicates the user is already authenticated? I am concerned about the risks of having to store and transmit credentials securely when I don't have to.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I later discovered that if you are logged on to the domain, that is sufficient for you to access the active directory store, without having to supply further credentials or impersonate an admin. And in some cases you can also access it without being logged in at all.